# Unable to Install Ubuntu 15.10 on an ASUS Vivo PC due to BusyBox issues

Tags: boot, partitioning, asus

I got a new ASUS VivoPC, haven't messed around with it yet. The only big modification that I've made is partitioning (divided it up to be linux-ready and has windows 8.1 within one of them).

I tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 on one of its partition and created a live USB, booted up, and ended with BusyBox (initramfs). I've tried and searched every single article and pages about ASUS-Ubuntu issues and BusyBox. But was never successful.

It's been a week since I've tried everything!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. So I installed ubuntu 15.04 and found out that, after all updates, the kernel 3.19.0-43 was installed. Now the vivo doesn't boot again. I changed some boot options in the Bios and changed it again. The next boot brings me to the extended options. There I choose booting with kernel 3.18.0-12. It runs fine. In synaptic I erased all 3.19.0-43-generic. From now my vivo runs perfect. But I think you have to erase the 3.19xx kernel after every system update. There is an other item for me to use ubuntu 15.04: From 15.10 the dolphin file manager doesn't work with samba shares. Maybe it will be fixed with 16.04 or later on.

Comment: "some boot options", "I think", "Maybe" – this sounds more like a comment than an answer. If you're certain about it, then it's an answer, if you're not, then it's a comment. Words like those mentioned before are a sign, that a message belongs in the comments.